# How to edit post settings in Ghost or Ghost Admin Interface?

Tags: ghost-blog

I basically want to edit the dropdown menu options for the Post access (add/remove public, members only, or other options). I also want to be able to have the 'Add feature image' in the post settings rather than in the post editor. How do I do that?

Also, is there any way to edit Ghost source code to make these or other changes? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing to do with Ghostscript or Ghostscript.NET

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

for doing those you should use source code version of the ghost-core and ghost-admin
download and install it from this guide :
https://ghost.org/docs/install/source/
and then edit where you want with searching elements in source code

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).